# Animate.css - Applying a onmouseover to a div to add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have imported the animate.css class which works perfectly when giving the class name, but when using applying a function to change the class when hovering over the div it does not work

```
  <div id="result" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; color: white" >
            animated bounce
        </div>
```

Here is the script

```
<script>
function animationHover(element, animation) {
    element = $(element);
    element.hover(
        function () {
            element.addClass('animated ' + animation);
        },
        function () {
            //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
            }, 2000);
        }
    );
};
</script>
```

And then finally calling the method:

```
animationHover('#result', 'tada');
```

But this doesn't do anything

All help is appreciated

Comment: using the same variable and scope issue i guess ... use another one ... try `var e = ..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simplify like this:

```js
function animationHover(element, animation) {
  $(element).hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('animated ' + animation);
    },
    function() {
      //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).removeClass('animated ' + animation);
      }, 1000);
    }
  );
};
animationHover('#result', 'tada');
```

```css
.animated {
  animation: anime 2s forwards;
}

.tada {
  background: blue;
  color: red;
}

@keyframes anime {
  to {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  animated bounce
</div>
```

Or something like this:

```js
function animationHover(element, animation) {
  $(element).hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('animated ' + animation)
      .on('animationend',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animation)
      });
    }
  );
};
animationHover('#result', 'tada');
```

```css
.animated {
  animation: anime 2s forwards;
}

.tada {
  background: blue;
  color: red;
}

@keyframes anime {
  to {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  animated bounce
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when copying your answer into my .net application it doesn't do anything :(

Comment: @lanes123 when running the site are you getting any error ?

Comment: its not getting any errors, when importing into my .net application when hovering over like in the code snippet it doesnt do anything

Even when imported into a normal html file within the appropriate tags (script, style) it still does not do anything. I am not sure if i am missing anything?

Comment: @lanes123 can you show me how you do with a normal HTML file ? maybe there is some issue with CSS

Comment: I posted below what i had put into the file, i appreciate the help mate!

Comment: @lanes123 ok you should remove it as it's not an answer :) and the issue is that the script need to be at the end, after the html and after the jquery

Comment: Mate, you are a lifesaver! worked like a charm thank you!

Comment: One last question sorry! To have the same effect but on a mouseclick, will it instead of "hover" be  "Click"?

Comment: using the same method, but changing the ".hover" to ".click" doesn't do anything? or does the function need changing

Comment: @lanes123 ah don't simply change :) the click take only one function, in this case consider my second code in my answer where you can change hover by click